# Should I use .env config file or just php array config?

Tags: php, environment-variables

I need environment specific config file which will not be included in the version control, file with php array seems to be a good choice especially considering that I can define values in desired type and will not need to convert them, but a lot of frameworks and libs use .env files. What are the advantages of .env files and why one should be using them?

Comment: Personally I don't mind any approach to this, if you go with any file based solution that isn't a .php file, make sure to keep it outside your web accessible folders, I will just add that I am a fan of .ini files, as php has a handy little function to convert them into php vars

Comment: what about .yml or .ini formats, many use them too..

Answer (score 3):

I like the way Laravel do it. It implements the config file and env file.

in `config/*.php`, you'll define things like:

```
<?php
      // config/app.php
      return array(
          'myconfig' => env('MYCONFIG', 'default')
      )
```

in `.env` file

```
MYCONFIG=something
```

so you'll only need to use `config` function everywhere.

`config('app.myconfig')`

btw, it's easy to implement both (isolated or together).

Answer (score 1):

.env files are a standard. It is simple to use and as it sounds like, it is environment independant.

You should definitively use this solution